# Alloy Show Functions in Submodule

Tags: alloy

I have a module test.als

```
module test

sig Sig1 {}

fun f:Sig1->Sig1 {iden}

run {#Sig1 = 1} for 1
```

and a submodule test2.als

```
module test2
open test

run{#Sig1=1}
```

But if I execute this and look at the model in the evaluator function f is not shown whereas it is in test. How can I change this?

Thanks

Edit: f is also not available when I go to Theme, so the issue is not that I have set it to be not shown

Comment: When you say 'look at', do you mean the evaluator?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have made that clearer. I edited the question.

Comment: I tried it and see that it shows `f` on the visualizer. I guess Alloy filters this, which  I think is a good idea. I am really not sure about the rules here.